# Same webservice port type with different credentials in a single Spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a webservice client, so far with fixed credentials. Now, I need the same application, but just with different credentials. I'd prefer to have just one application running. One of the two possible webservice credentials shall later be chosen according to the status of my users, eg `ADMIN` or `USER`.

Based on that status I'd like to delegate on one or the other credentials.

Problem: I'm creating my webservice ports using `Spring` injection, and would like to continue this approach. Anyhow, when I now need 2nd credentials, I probably have to create a 2nd port for the webservice client.

BUT: I cannot create two beans of the same type, of course.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public WsPort getPort() {
        WsPort port = new MyWebService().getWsPort(); //these are auto generated classes from a wsdl
        addCredentials(port, username1, pass1); //sets the HTTP header credentials
        return port;
    }

    //this won't work as WsPort bean must be unique
    @Bean
    public WsPort getPort2() {
        WsPort port = new MyWebService().getWsPort();
        addCredentials(port, username2, pass2);
        return port;
    }
}
```

I'm using the port so far like:

```
@Service
public class MyClient {
    @Autowired
    private WsPort port;

}
```

Of course this I cannot use it like this anymore, as I have to chose the port based on the user status.

How could I have two objects (webservice port in my case) of the same type, but with different "content" (http credentials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to give them different names:

```
@Bean(name = "port1")
public WsPort getPort() {
    WsPort port = new MyWebService().getWsPort();
    addCredentials(port, username1, pass1);
    return port;
}

@Bean(name = "port2")
public WsPort getPort2() {
    WsPort port = new MyWebService().getWsPort();
    addCredentials(port, username2, pass2);
    return port;
}
```

And use a qualifier in your client:

```
@Service
public class MyClient {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("port1")
    private WsPort port;
}
```

Or get the instance from the context

```
@Service
public class MyClient {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    ...

    public void myMethod(){
        context.getBean("port1", WsPort.class).doWhatever();        
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
You could also have only 1 port as a `prototype` bean to obtain a new instance each time, and set the login details accordingly from your client

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public WsPort getPort() {
    return new MyWebService().getWsPort();
}

@Service
public class MyClient {
    @Autowired
    private WsPort port;

    ...

    public void myMethod(){
        addCredentials(port, username2, pass2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like that approach. No I'd like to prevent prototype scope as this would generate lots of objects constantly throughout the day...

Comment: I'd be very interested in understanding why you consider this to be a problem / downside

Comment: As far as I know, the purpose of autowired singleton beans in spring is to prevent the JVM constantly creating, destroying and garbage collecting instances of the same object. Thus, as I have to preconfigure every webservice port (with http headers, compression, credentials etc), it would probably be nice if spring would reuse each port, in spite of recreating it for every single request (which can be a few per second per user). Wouldn't you aggree with that?

Comment: It's really up to you to decide whether you want a singleton or a prototype, depending on your requirements and your implementation plan: does your bean have a state? will it be accessed simultaneously by multiple threads? etc. Regarding `if spring would reuse each port`, if you take a look at my "edit example" you'll notice a small problem: although the port was defined as a prototype, the client is a singleton. Thus you'll be using always the same client and implicitly port. You can also reuse a prototype instance as long as you don't request a new bean from spring on each request